# Deleting each character in s1 that matches any character in s2

Tags: c

Can anyone see what's wrong with my code? Thank you so much!

`squeeze2` takes as its parameter two char arrays. It deletes each character in the first array that matches any character in the second array. For example: if the first is "hello" and the second is "ea", then the first array will become "hllo".

For every iteration of the outer loop, `a[i]` is a specific number. Let's call it `c`. Each time a non-`c` occurs, it is copied into the current `k` position, and only then is `k` incremented to be ready for the next character.

```
void squeeze2(char s[], char a[]){
    int i, j, k;/*Remove elements of a from s*/
    i=j=k=0;
    while(a[i++] != '\0'){
        k = 0;
        while(s[j++]!= '\0'){
            if(s[j]!= a[i]){
                s[k++] = s[j];
            }
        }
    }
    s[k] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: We're not mind-readers. Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Your first problem is the one-character variables. That's clouding the actual problem.

Comment: What does it do?  What do you expect it to do?  Please provide some input/output samples.

Comment: squeeze2 takes as its parameter two char arrays. It deletes each character in the first array that matches any character in the second array. For example: if the first is "hello" and the second is "ea", then the first array will become "hllo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is close to working but you just did a couple of silly mistakes. E.g. while (s[j++]... but then you check s[j] in the next line, it should be the old value of j, not the new value. Also you need to reset j to 0 before the loop.

I'd suggest changing both loops to standard for loops. Also you can use `const` and `restrict` to help your compiler out:

```
void squeeze2(char *restrict s, char const *restrict remove)
{
/* Loop through 'remove' taking each char out of `s` */
    for (; *remove; ++remove)
    {
        size_t out = 0;
        for (size_t in = 0; s[in]; ++in)
        {
            if ( s[in] != *remove )
                s[out++] = s[in];
        }
        s[out] = 0;
    }
}
```

Actually my preference would be to have the loops the other way around: loop through `s`; and use the `strchr` function to decide whether to keep the current character. It's easier to read, and does fewer writes:

```
void squeeze2(char *restrict s, char const *restrict remove)
{
/* Loop through 's', only keeping chars that are not in 'remove' */
    char *out = s;

    for (; *s; ++s)
    {
        if ( !strchr(remove, *s) )
            *out++ = *s;
    }
    *out = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your problem.
Let s1 be the string that needs to have letters removed, and let s2 be the string containing the elements to look for.

```
void squeeze2(char s1[], char s2[]){
  int i, j, k;/*Remove elements of a from s*/
  i=j=k=0;

  /* For each character in s2... */
  while(s2[i] != '\0'){ // Note change of i++ to i

      /* Search for the character in s1...*/
      j = k = 0; // Counters for string1
      while(s1[j]!= '\0'){

        /* If we find a match, remove the character... ('shift' the remaining characters 1 index to the left, overwriting the current character)*/
        if(s1[j]== s2[i]){
            k = j //Start at j
            while(s1[k] != '\0'){ //again, I don't start with k++, just k
              s1[k] = s1[k+1]; // The null-terminator gets copied too.
              k++;
            }
        j++;
        }
      }
      i++;
  }
  //The following line is not necessary because the null-terminator is copied
  //s1[k] = '\0';  
  }
```

Please remember to mark correct answers.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you so much! What was wrong with my code, though?

Comment: There were several things wrong with your code.

First, you started your loops with "while( <array>[i++] != '\0')..." which means inside the loop i will never be 0 (do you know why?). So you will always skip the first character in each array.

And you should reset j = 0 before you start the second while loop.

Instead of incrementing counters during the while() condition, increment them at the end of the loop like I did, or be more careful and account for the increment within the loop.

Actually, looking at your code it looks a little more efficient than mine, if you fixed the semantic errors.

Comment: I will add, that in my code the null-terminator doesn't need to be manually inserted at the end, but if you kept your code the way it is and fix the semantic errors, you would need to manually place the null-terminator there, as you've done :).